# Сохранение данных CakePHp

Tags: php

Всем привет подскажите какие есть функции чтобы узнать ошибку при сохранении данных.Сами данные получаю с помощью метода Jquery serialize() и после этого передаю с помощью Ajax в контроллер но они не хотят сохранятся в базу(

```
$('#add_new_player').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $.ajax({
        url:"/Group/Players/add_player",
        success:function(data) {
            pl_dialog.html(data)
            pl_dialog.dialog("open")
            $('#close_dialog_pl').click(function() {
                pl_dialog.dialog("close")
            })
            $('#add_player').click(function() {
                var data = $('#AddForm').serialize()
                $.post("/Group/Players/player_save", {data:data})
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Вот код контроллера

```
function player_save() {
    if (!empty($this -> request -> data)) {
        $this -> Player -> save($this -> request -> data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post("/Group/Players/player_save",{data:data})
```

вместо этого лучше использовать $.ajax({}) и в консоле посмотреть об ошибке, и еще при сохранении в этом случае попробуй так

```
$this->Player->save($this->request->data['User']);
```

поменяй имя User на имя контроллера куда идут данные, да еще и имя public новерное стоит добавить перед function()